# Python shelve ignoring writeback=True

Tags: python, shelve

I have a problem where changes in a list are not reflected in the associated shelf (Python 2.6.9). Consider the following minimal example

File Context.py:

```
import shelve

class Cont:
    shelf = shelve.open( STATUSFILE, protocol = 0, writeback = True )
```

File test.py:

```
from Context import Cont

class T:
    jobQueue = list()

    @classmethod
    def save(cls):
        cls.jobQueue = [1,2,3]
        Cont.shelf['queue'] = cls.jobQueue
        Cont.shelf.sync()
        print(Cont.shelf['queue'])
        cls.jobQueue.pop()
        print(Cont.shelf['queue'])
        print(id(cls.jobQueue))
        print(id(Cont.shelf['queue']))
```

Output:

```
[1,2,3]
[1,2,3]
7804904
7899472
```

First, I assumed the second list output to be`[1,2]`. Second, why are the ids different? When assigning the list, only a reference should be copied, keeping the id intact.
<strike>The strange thing is that I cannot reproduce that on the Python shell. There the output ids are the same and the shelfed list shows the change on jobQueue.</strike>
It seems that when executing my program the `writeback=True` is ignored. I am greatful for every hint!

EDIT: I did reproduce the problem on the shell with the given minimal example. May this have something to do with the class structure (I'm pretty new to objective Python)? I can imagine that class Cont does not know class T and hence cannot store a reference to T.jobQueue but rather a copy of the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Without shelf.sync()**:

```
def save(cls):
    Cont.shelf['queue'] = cls.jobQueue   #1
    print(Cont.shelf['queue'])           #2
    # [1, 2, 3]        
    cls.jobQueue.pop()                   #3
    print(Cont.shelf['queue'])           #4
    # [1, 2]
```

1. With writeback=True, assignments store the key/value pair in shelf.cache as well as shelf.dict.
2. Attempts to retrieve the data at key `'queue'` from shelf.cache.
3. modifies `cls.jobQueue`, which **is** the same object as the one
   retrieved from the cache
4. retrieves the data at key `'queue'` from shelf.cache again. Since the cache holds a refence to `cls.jobQueue`, this is the same object.

However, **if you call shelf.sync()**:

```
def save(cls):
    Cont.shelf['queue'] = cls.jobQueue   
    Cont.shelf.sync()                    #1
    print(Cont.shelf['queue'])           #2
    # [1, 2, 3]        
    cls.jobQueue.pop()                   #3
    print(Cont.shelf['queue'])           #4
    # [1, 2, 3]
```

1. The shelve file is updated, [**and the cache is reset to an empty dict**](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c5464268aead/Lib/shelve.py#l166).
2. Attempts to retrieve the data at key `'queue'` from shelf.cache. Since the cache is empty, a new **copy** of the data is retrieved from the shelve file.
3. modifies `cls.jobQueue`, which **is not** the same object as the copy just retrieved
4. The cache is still empty, so this retrieves a new copy from the unupdated shelve file again

Comment: You are right! Problem is, I Have to sync every change. So I can use the way described in my answer or I can do `cls.jobQueue = Cont.shelf['queue']` after every sync().

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of testing I found the problem:
The line `Cont.shelf.sync()` changes the id (and reference) of the data included in shelf. Hence the changes in `cls.jobQueue` will not be reflected after the `.sync()` call.
While the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) of the shelve module does not forbid using it the way I did, it seems to work properly only the documented way. This means that all changes should be made like this:
`Cont.shelf['queue'].pop()`
or by reassignin `jobQueue` to the shelf after every modification.